# In Excel, why is the following VBA taking so long to run?

Tags: excel, vba

It is taking over 900 seconds to write an array to a worksheet.  The array is 860 items long.  Any clue why this is taking so long?  It seems to take more time every time I run it.  I know my PC isn't the issue as I have a new laptop with an i7, 32GIGS rams, and 1 tb SSD.

```
x = 2
y = 1
TotTime = 0
For i = LBound(arrModel) To UBound(arrModel) 'Write array to worksheet
    Cells(x, 61).Value = arrModel(i)
    Cells(x, 62).Value = 1
    Cells(x, 63).Value = y
    If x <= shiftBreakPoint Then
        Cells(x, 64).Value = firstShiftMPJ
        Cells(x, 65).Value = 1
        TotTime = TotTime + firstShiftMPJ
    Else
        Cells(x, 64).Value = secondShiftMPJ
        Cells(x, 65).Value = 2
        TotTime = TotTime + secondShiftMPJ
    End If
    Cells(x, 66).Value = TotTime
    y = y + 1
    x = x + 1
Next i
```

Comment: runs instantly for me.

Comment: Do not loop to put the data.  Create an output 2D variant array of the correct size and loop the data into that.  Then bulk load the data all at once into the sheet.

Comment: Do you have formulae which are dependent on the values that you are inserting?  Try setting Calculation to Manual and see if that makes a difference.  And as @Scott says use a variant array.  The effect is dramatic.

Comment: Sorry I should have included the code.  I turn off calculation just before and turn it in right after.  @ScottCraner, How do I do that?

Comment: `Dim OutArray() as Variant` | `Redim OutArray(1 to UBound(arrModel),1 to 6) as Variant` then instead of fill the cells on the sheet you fill the array using the same logic `OutArray(x,1) = arrModel(i)` and so on for the 6 columns.  Then after the array is full you would just assign the values to the worksheet `Cells(2,61).Resize(UBound(arrModel),6).Value = OutArray`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you write to a cell the screen refreshes, and the worksheet re-calculates. Thiis takes time. You can prevent that from happening, but I suggest to improve the writing process without loops so you don't have to manage screen updates and calculations manually.

In the code below a large array `vals()` is declared that holds all the values to be written on the worksheet exactly. Once filled, the writing happens with one command, `r_out.Resize(n, 6).Value2 = vals`. This is amazingly fast, and it triggers only one re-calculate and one screen refresh.

```
...
Dim vals() As Variant
Dim TotTime As Double
Dim r_out As Range
Set r_out = Range("BI2")

Dim i As Long, n As Long, j As Long, x As Long
n = UBound(arrModel) - LBound(arrModel) + 1

' Declare an array and fill with all the values
ReDim vals(1 To n, 1 To 6)
TotTime = 0#
For i = 1 To n
    ' x tracks the row in the worksheet
    x = r_out.Row + i - 1
    ' j tracks the index of arrModel
    j = LBound(arrModel) + i - 1
    vals(i, 1) = arrModel(j)
    vals(i, 2) = 1#
    vals(i, 3) = i
    If x <= shiftBreakPoint Then
        vals(i, 4) = firstShiftMPJ
        vals(i, 5) = 1#
        TotTime = TotTime + firstShiftMPJ
    Else
        vals(i, 4) = secondShiftMPJ
        vals(i, 5) = 2#
        TotTime = TotTime + secondShiftMPJ
    End If
    vals(i, 6) = TotTime
Next i

' Now write the values onto the worksheet
r_out.Resize(n, 6).Value2 = vals
...
```

<sub>Note that `Cells(2,61)` is the same as `Range("BI2")`.</sub>

---

If all of this a bridge too far for you and you want to speed up the existing code then try the following:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
x = 2
y = 1
TotTime = 0#
For i = LBound(arrModel) To UBound(arrModel) 'Write array to worksheet
            
    If x <= shiftBreakPoint Then
        TotTime = TotTime + firstShiftMPJ
        Cells(x, 61).Resize(1, 6).Value2 = _
            Array(arrModel(i), 1#, y, firstShiftMPJ, 1#, TotTime)
    Else
        TotTime = TotTime + secondShiftMPJ
        Cells(x, 61).Resize(1, 6).Value2 = _
            Array(arrModel(i), 1#, y, secondShiftMPJ, 2#, TotTime)
    End If
    
    y = y + 1
    x = x + 1
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, like several people already mentioned, if you want to transfer array content to a range (quickly), you should not loop like you did.
 You could directly paste the array to a range with corresponding size (sometimes may require "worksheetfunction.transpose").
You may refer to THE late but great Mr. Chip Pearson here:
[VBA Arrays And Worksheet Ranges](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx)

There are some other steps that you can follow to improve the speed of transfer like disabling worksheet recalculations, disable screenupdating etc.